# dataset was not found in location EU (ga_sessions data)

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following problem.
I've created the big query export adjusting the linkage from google analytics console.
And as expected there is a dataset created in the Big Query storage where the data is flowing on the daily basis.
The timezone and country in the GA account is Germany, but the location of the final data set in BQ is US (althoug I didn't specify it when I was linking the data), that causes some issues when connecting the data from this property with the other data I have in the storage.

My questions are:

1. Can someone please explain why it could have happened?
2. Is there any solution except copying the whole dataset to the new location?
3. Are there any other potential problems with having the dataset in the different location from the other datasets? (except of not able to query them at once?)

Really appreciate your help!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The data is located in US because it is the default location for the GA export data to BQ feature. It is documented [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092?hl=en) (Step 2.1).
   Consider localizing your dataset to the E.U. at this step.

> Data is geolocated in the U.S. by default. Localizing your data to the
> EU after the initial export can cause issues with querying across
> BigQuery regions. Resolving those issue may require a transfer of
> data, which has associated costs. We recommend creating the
> E.U.-localized dataset at this point in order to avoid any negative
> side effects.
>
> Google Analytics BigQuery Export is incompatible with GCP policies
> that prevent dataset creation in the US. If you have such a policy on
> your GCP project, you will have to remove it to export your data to
> the EU.

2. The only solution in order to have the GA data in EU is to copy the whole dataset to a new one located in EU with a different name. Then, delete the original one, and copy the new one again to the original dataset.
3. Your main blocker is what you have mentioned. You won't be able to JOIN GA data with any other data located in other region. In addition, there might be legal issues because of the GDPR.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alvaro for the detailed answer; So as I understood if copy the data set to the new one and recreate it in datasource with the same dataset id as view id, created in the right location , then GA will be correctly sent to the new one the next day, right?

Comment: did the changes and it worked, thanks one more time :)

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. Please, consider accept the answer so others can benefit from it :)